# What is the purpose of GetPrivateProfileString?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, function

I have come across the term `GetPrivateProfileString` in a C++ program. Could anyone give me a simple explanation of the use of this function?

The code on my page is:

```
GetPrivateProfileString("files", "directory", "/mediadb/files/", directory, os.path.getsize(directory), "apache")
```

Comment: @Pop, closing the question just stops further answers, it does not delete it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`GetPrivateProfileString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353%28VS.85%29.aspx) reads values from .ini files.

Way back when, in the days of 16-bit Windows, it was the way to read and write application configuration data. Back then applications stored their configuration in a shared .ini file that lived in the system directory, called win.ini. Bad times!

To read from win.ini you called `GetProfileString()`. The private in `GetPrivateProfileString()` is indicative of the fact that this wonderful function allowed you to access an .ini file other than win.ini, i.e. one private to your application. If I recall correctly (and my memory is hazy), most applications carried on using win.ini for years and years after it was officially frowned upon to do so.

It so happens that `GetPrivateProfileString()` is an incredibly wrinkly beast with terrible performance characteristics and hard to understand oddities. I personally avoid it like the plague and if I have to process .ini files I use bespoke code to do so.

Raymond Chen has a nice [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/26/6523907.aspx) about why .ini files were deprecated in favour of the registry.

Comment: +1 for not simply copy-pasting from MSDN. But I think `GetPrivateProfileString()` actually reads from an application's private .ini file. The one you're talking about that reads from the common Win.ini file is `GetProfileString()`.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks for that. My memory is hazy. It was a long time ago! I've updated the answer so that hopefully it is more accurate.

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your time and patience @David Heffernan!!

Comment: I don't agree that the function is solely a relic of 16-bit Windows, nor that it's a wrinkly beast with hard to understand oddities.  It's quite simple to understand, actually.  I wouldn't recommend using it over better methods, but it's still a supported member of the Win32 API and still functions exactly as described in the documentation.  It has some benefits over the truly wrinkly beast known as the registry, which is really not much more than a shiny version of win.ini.  Reality is, .ini files were just a simple version of .config files favored by .net today.

Comment: What makes GetPrivateProfileString an incredibly wrinkly beast with oddities?  I'm genuinely interested.  And for most apps, I don't see how the performance characteristics would matter...  App configuration usually isn't the bottleneck...  (Obviously, INI files themselves have many flaws as outlined by Raymond Chen in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/26/6523907.aspx - but these seem like INI format flaws and not wrinkles with the GetPrivateProfileString implementation.)

Comment: And with the resurgence of `app.config`, `web.config`, and `appsettings.json`, people have rediscovered some of the virtues of `.ini` files; while not caring about the downsides no granular security and DoS. But it turns out we just don't *care* about those things.

Comment: I don't agree. It is not important for .ini file to be in system directory. It can be in application (exe) directory or any other directory. And .ini file format is not bad - it is very similar to .conf file in Linux/Unix world. Whether function is for compatibility is disputable question. It exists and works. Even with Unicode files!

Answer (score 2):

It's [for reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353%28VS.85%29.aspx) from .ini files.  It's an old win16 API.  You shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Retrieves a string from the specified section in an initialization
>   file.
>
> Note
>
> This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit
>   Windows-based applications. Applications should store initialization
>   information in the registry.

**Syntax**

```
DWORD WINAPI GetPrivateProfileString(
  __in   LPCTSTR lpAppName,
  __in   LPCTSTR lpKeyName,
  __in   LPCTSTR lpDefault,
  __out  LPTSTR lpReturnedString,
  __in   DWORD nSize,
  __in   LPCTSTR lpFileName
);
```

Comment: This isn't much help. What is an initialization file? I think smurf needs help at that level rather than an MSDN copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

This retrieves configuration information from an .ini file