# GetPrivateProfileString doesn't work if path contains special chars

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine, .net-2.0, class-library

i made a dll in c# framework.net 2.0 with this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Read Data Value From the Ini File
/// </summary>
/// <PARAM name="Section"></PARAM>
/// <PARAM name="Key"></PARAM>
/// <PARAM name="Path"></PARAM>
/// <returns></returns>
public string IniReadValue(string Section, string Key)
{
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
    int i = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 255, this.path);
    return temp.ToString();
}
```

the function is declared like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);
```

and if I create a winform project that calls this code works fine, also if the ini file is inside a documents folder and the user have a special char like `ç` or `Д`.

this dll I need to use in unity3d, and works fine but if the folder contains the special chars above *(example)* it doesn't work and return an empty string..

any ideas?

Comment: How did you declare this function?

Comment: @RezaAghaei added a declaration in the question :)

Comment: Do you really need this function? This is old, deprecated native function call (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336185/what-is-the-purpose-of-getprivateprofilestring), why don't you read ini manually?

Comment: thanks @Skyblade, but reading ini manually what do you mean?

Comment: @ghiboz I mean using your own code. It is not that hard, while you can search for existing implementations.

Comment: @ghiboz I copied win.ini to a folder named `@"d:\ДFolder\"` and tested with section `"Mail"`, key `"MAPI"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
             string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal,
             int size, string filePath);
```