# GetPrivateProfileString without remove quotes

Tags: c#, ini

I have a ini file content below:

```
[Test]
Item="123","456"
```

I use the code below to parse the value.

But I found it didn't return the value I expected.

Seems like the function will auto remove first and last quote.

Any solution to fix this?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(500);
WINAPI.GetPrivateProfileString("Test", "Item", "", stringBuilder,500, "D:\\Test.ini");
var _value = stringBuilder.ToString(0, stringBuilder.Length); //get 123","456 instead "123","456"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that even 2011 people tried to stay away from `GetPrivateProfileString` and it's oddities: [What is the purpose of GetPrivateProfileString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336185/what-is-the-purpose-of-getprivateprofilestring)

So maybe you should store your application configuration somewhere else, for example an app.config file or the registry. Or you could simply read it with custom code:

```
public static string? GetIniValue(string iniPath, string sectionName, string key)
{
    if (!File.Exists(iniPath))
    {
        return null;
    }

    string sectionHeader = $"[{sectionName}]";
    return File.ReadLines(iniPath)
        .SkipWhile(l => !l.Equals(sectionHeader, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Skip(1) // skip header
        .TakeWhile(l => l.Contains('='))
        .Select(GetMatchingKeyValueOrNull)
        .FirstOrDefault(value => value != null);

    string? GetMatchingKeyValueOrNull(string line)
    {
        string[] arr = line.Split('=');
        return arr.Length > 1 && arr[0].Trim().Equals(key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            ? arr[1].Trim() : null;
    }
}
```

---

```
string testItemValue = GetIniValue(@"D:\\Test.ini", "Test", "Item");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add new double quotes at the beginning and end.

```
[Test]
Item=""123","456","789","abc","def""
```

Comment: Thanks. It did works. But for some reason I can't ensure the value will all add new double quotes since it is maintain by other user. Thanks anyway.